# Creating a modal dialog on the fly in Bootsrap3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way I can create on the fly a modal dialog starting from a DOM node or a AJAX call?

Right now, I have to put

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

```

I would like something like

```
<img src='' id="x">
<script>
$('#x').modal({title:'Image',otherOption:true});
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to completely create the HTML structure in your first code snippet, inserting the desired body into the `modal-body`, and then inserting the modal into the page and showing it. Or, you'll have to have this HTML structure sitting in your DOM, hidden, and replace the `modal-body` content when you want to show something specific, and show the modal.

Comment: Thank you Ian. you confirmed my fears :)

Comment: It shouldn't be a big deal though. Just create a function that creates the modal (generating the HTML), adding specific content (passed as parameters), and adding it to the page - I made one in the past to do this exact thing. I also have it removing itself from the DOM when it's closed.

Comment: @Ian, could you please post that code as an answer? I have the same requirement just now.

Answer (score 19):

```
var popupTemplate =
  '<div class="modal fade">' +
  '  <div class="modal-dialog">' +
  '    <div class="modal-content">' +
  '      <div class="modal-header">' +
  '        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>' +
  '        <h4 class="modal-title">I am a dialog</h4>' +
  '      </div>' +
  '      <div class="modal-body" />' +
  '      <div class="modal-footer">' +
  '        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>' +
  '        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>' +
  '      </div>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '</div>';

$(popupTemplate).modal()
```

Also, [BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/) does this.

Comment: The example has a syntax error. `I'm a dialog` should be `I\'m a dialog`